# Как модель памяти с++ определяет тип данных?

Tags: c++, ассемблер, память, компилятор

Когда мы компилируем код

```
int i = 0;
```

Компилятор присваивает вместо переменной i какой то адрес в памяти (начальную ячейку) и далее работает с ней например считывает из нее данные.
У меня вопрос

1. Как при чтении компилятор понимает что нужно прочитать именно 4байта (int) ведь тип данных не храниться на сколько я знаю, а передаем мы ему только начальный адрес.
2. Как это работает если по адресу у нас лежит не int, а длинная строка или какой либо динамический тип который может увеличиваться, получается конец данных будет постоянно смещаться отодвигая все что записано за ним?

Comment: Разделите время исполнений программы, и время компиляции, в течение которого тип вполне может существовать. Все встанет на места.

Comment: *"Смешались в кучу люди кони"*... Для начала разберитесь с тем, что такое компилятор и какие действия он выполняет, затем с объектной моделью. А то вы даже компиляцию и исполнение путаете.

Comment: Согласен не корректно написал вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это в скомпилированной программе нет (явной) информации о длине int. А во время компиляции компилятор то знает, что `i` типа `int` и значит у нее определенная длина. А значит при чтении нужно читать 4 байта (если длина `int` именно 4 байта).

Для строк используется либо формат, где конец помечается нулем, либо в отдельной переменной хранится явно длина и код использует длину, чтоб обращаться только в рамках фактической длины строки.

Компилятор об этом "не знает" в том смысле, что он ничего специального не делает. Это сама программа обращается только в рамках строки, т.е. например, делает цикл от начала, т.е. от байта на который указывает указатель на начало строки, и пока не встретит нулевой байт. Компилятор знает тип "указатель на байт" и в обращениях к элементам вставляет код, который, скажем, читает байт по указателю (тут длина строки никак не участвует). То что под строку выделено, скажем, 10 байт, компилятор не знает.

Comment: т.е. грубо говоря компилятор в итоге сделает команду - прочитай 4 байта начиная с адреса такого то? А для строки например это может быть команда - читай все символы пока не встретишь определенную последовательность означающую завершение?

Comment: Если очень грубо говоря, то да. Но только нет такой команды "читай все символы пока не встретишь 0". Это уже в самой программе есть код, в котором такая логика, а компилятор лишь эту логику переводим в машинный код. На уровне компилятора идет работа с типами данных типа int или "указатель на байт", и только на это уровне и об этих типах компилятор знает, там проблем с размерами нет. Дополнил ответ в этой части.

Comment: Понял. А в случае с int т.к. он строго 4 байта, будет прям в скомпилированной программе инструкция четкая "прочитай 4 байта" ?

Comment: Да, будет именно такая инструкция.

Answer (score 2):

> Как при чтении компилятор понимает что нужно прочитать именно 4байта (int) ведь тип данных не храниться на сколько я знаю, а передаем мы ему только начальный адрес.

*Компилятор*, который компилирует исходный код, знает об этом — потому что знает, что переменная объявлена как `int`, а размеры типов ему известны. Так что он сгенерирует правильный *код*? который и будет перемещать 4 байта куда надо.

> Как это работает если по адресу у нас лежит не int, а длинная строка или какой либо динамический тип который может увеличиваться, получается конец данных будет постоянно смещаться отодвигая все что записано за ним?

Вопрос, как бы сказать... как по мне, некорректен. Если там лежит строка — то будет сгенерирован код для работы со строкой (с проверкой, например, завершающего нулевого символа etc). Динамический тип — что именно вы имеете в виду? Какой-нибудь вектор? Но при присваивании одного вектора другому не будет простой инструкции переноса из одного места памяти в другое, как и при копировании строки, например. Это будет целый ряд простых команд процессора, целая своя подпрограмма. Так что коду не надо знать о размере такого меняемого во время работы объекта — он просто тем или иным способом будет вычислен.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Answer (score 2):

1. Каждый компилятор сам решает сколько байтов в int. Выбирая компилятор ты автоматически соглашаешься с его "мнением", вот к примеру мнение [Компиляторы Microsoft C++](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=msvc-160). Во время компиляции компилятор выбирает команды соответствующие заранее оговоренной размерности.
2. Что касается твоего вопроса о различии при чтении строки и int, так их чтение с точки зрения машинной логики ничем не отличается, при работе со строками они также читаются по одному символу за раз, за исключением случаем когда при помощи специализированного сета intrinsics предусмотрена их обработка по 16/32/64 байта за раз.
3. При чтении строки дополнительно предусматривается проверка символа на значение NULL которое означает конец строки, столкнувшись с таким символом "нормальны" код завершит обработку строки, а "кривой" продолжит читать всю оставшуюся память пока не превысит права доступа к памяти и программа не упадет, со словами "инструкция ХХХ обратилась к памяти ХХХ, которая не может быть READ".